# router port forwarding to server not worked in iphone

Tags: django, iphone, server, portforwarding

I developed a simple website using Django framework for some tasks,
the Django server currently running on my local network but in some case
there is a user wan't to access website outside local network (from home)
so I configured the port forwarding in my router to host where django server run into it
the website runs on different devices and operating systems like linux, windows and android but except for the iPhone
and this error appear in server

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socketserver.py", line 691, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/mahmoud/Downloads/project/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 229, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/mahmoud/Downloads/project/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 237, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```